# Phonegap/Angular - angular.element().scope() not working

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm overriding the back-button behaviour for Android/WP8 for my Phonegap/Angular app.  I had implemented it a few weeks ago, and it was working like a charm. But, due to a repository blunder I made, that part of the code became lost. So today I've been recreating it, but no matter what I do, I cannot get to my handleBack() function in my MainController.

In my index.html, I'm including all my various .js files in the header, and here's my body:

```
<body ng-view ng-class="slide" ng-controller="MainController" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady(event){
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBackButton, false);
        }

        function handleBackButton(event){
            alert("entered handleBackButton");
            angular.element('[ng-controller=MainController]').scope().handleBack(event);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

and here's my MainController:

```
.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', '$location', 'currentLocale', 'Auth',  
function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, $location, currentLocale, Auth) {
$scope.slide = '';
$rootScope.back = function() {
  $(window).blur();
  $scope.slide = 'slide-right';
  if (typeof (navigator.app) !== "undefined") {
    navigator.app.backHistory();
  } else {
    $window.history.back();
  }
}

$rootScope.go = function(path, direction) {
  $(window).blur();
  $scope.slide = typeof direction !== 'undefined' ? direction : 'slide-left';
  $location.url(path);
}

$rootScope.login = function() {
  $scope.slide = 'slide-right';
  $location.path('/');
  $window.localStorage.clear();
}

$rootScope.logout = function() {
  if(navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?", 
                                    function(index){
                                      if(index == 1){
                                        Auth.logout(function(data) {
                                            $rootScope.login();
                                        });
                                      }
                                    }, 
                                    "Confirm")) {
    Auth.logout(function(data) {
        $rootScope.login();
    });
  }
}

$rootScope.showAlert = function(message, title, labels, callback) {
  var bl = (labels) ? labels : currentLocale.OK;
  var t = (title) ? title : "";
  var cb = (callback) ? callback : function(){};
  navigator.notification.alert(
    message,
    cb,
    t,
    bl
  );
}


$scope.handleBack = function(e){
  alert("back button tapped");
  if ( $location.url() == "/" ) {
    if (navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?")) {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  else if( $location.url() == "/home" ) {
    $rootScope.back();
    $window.localStorage.clear();
  }
  else{
    $rootScope.back();
  }
}
}])
```

I get the "enter handleBackButton" alert, but it isn't hitting entering the alert in $scope.handleBack().

What am I doing wrong????

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller=moviescontroller]')).scope().RedirectMovieDetails();
```

use  like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.